# RecyclerView items dissapear after transition to another fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room

RecyclerView doesn't show items that I observe from database when I'm lauching my app. They only appear when I return from `AddSceneFragment` and dissapear after switching to different fragment.

This is my `SceneFragment` where I have my RecyclerView with the list of scenes of current project

```
class SceneFragment : Fragment(), ScenesAdapter.RawClickListener {
    private lateinit var viewModel: DataViewModel
    private var _binding: FragmentSceneBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private var projectID: Int = 0
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentSceneBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)


        //RecyclerView
        val adapter = ScenesAdapter(this@SceneFragment)
        val rv = binding.ScenesList
        rv.adapter = adapter

        rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(DataViewModel::class.java)

        //Get the id of current project
        viewModel.currentProject.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { project->
            projectID = project.id
        })

        //Get the list of all scenes in the project
        viewModel.getScenesInProject(projectID).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {scene->
            adapter.setData(scene)

        })

        //Add new scene
        binding.addSceneButton.setOnClickListener {
            val action = SceneFragmentDirections.actionSceneFragmentToAddSceneFragment()
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    }
```

This is adapter:

```
class ScenesAdapter(val listener: RawClickListener):RecyclerView.Adapter<ScenesAdapter.SceneHolder>() {
    private var scenesList = emptyList<Scene>()
    class SceneHolder(val binding: ProjectRawBinding, val listener: RawClickListener):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SceneHolder {
        val binding = ProjectRawBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
        return SceneHolder(binding, listener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return scenesList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SceneHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentScene = scenesList[position]

        //Set the item name
        holder.binding.projectNameTxt.text = currentScene.scene_name


        //Move to the SceneDetails fragment
        holder.binding.rawLayout.setOnClickListener{
            val action = SceneFragmentDirections.actionSceneFragmentToSceneDetails(currentScene)
            holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }


        // Delete current scene
        holder.binding.deleteProjectID.setOnClickListener {
            listener.deleteScene(currentScene)
        }

    }

    fun setData(scene: List<Scene>) {
        this.scenesList = scene
        notifyDataSetChanged()

    }

    interface RawClickListener{
        fun deleteScene(scene: Scene)
    }

}
```

This my view model:

```
class DataViewModel(application:Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
     val readAllProjects: LiveData<List<Projects>>
    val currentProject: MutableLiveData<Projects> = MutableLiveData()
    private val repository: ProjectsRepository

    init{
        val projectsDao = ProjectsDatabase.getDatabase(application).projectsDao()
        repository = ProjectsRepository(projectsDao)
        readAllProjects = repository.readAllProjects
    }

    ...

    fun getScenesInProject(projectID: Int): LiveData<List<Scene>> {
            return repository.getProjectWithScenes(projectID)
    }
```

My DAO:

```
@Dao
interface ProjectsDao {

    // Scenes related queries

    @Insert
    suspend fun addScene(scene: Scene)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteScene(scene: Scene)

    @Query("DELETE FROM scene")
    suspend fun deleteAllScenes()

    @Update
    suspend fun updateScene(scene: Scene)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM scene WHERE projectID = :projectID")
    fun getAllScenes(projectID: Int): LiveData<List<Scene>>
}
```

I think the query to get all scenes is correct, but the RecyclerView doesn't want to update items that I observe. I tried to use `notifyDataSetChanged()`, but it seems that doesn't work either or I am using it wrong.

Comment: That's how the fragment's lifecycle works. You'll want to override the OnResume method and in there, reload your recyclerView.